# How to get my microphone status on discord

Tags: discord

I am creating light for desk, this light will be green when my microphone is active on Discord, and red when my microphone is muted. So I want to get my microphone status from discord. But I don't know-how.

1. How to get my microphone status from discord when I am not in a voice chat too?

I know how to get microphone status when I am sitting on voice chat but I want to get this information the whole time.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem ? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing...

Comment: Hi, I didn't :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Client#voiceStateUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) to detect when you change if you are muted or not.

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  if (oldState.member.user.id !== "youridhere") return // make sure its only checking for your microhpone
  if (newState.mute) { // check if mic is muted
    setLightColor("red") //if true make light red
  } else {
    setLightColor("green") //if false make light green
  }
})
```

Comment: It's working great when I am on voice chat. But I want to this working the whole time, so I want to this working too when I am not on the channel.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do this !

I made a custom Node.js app using [rpcord](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpcord).
It requires a registered discord app (no need to validate it). You will have to manually link it to Discord using the URL Generator with the `rpc` and `rpc.voice.read` scopes, then copy/paste the Client ID, Client Secret and Discord Token in the constants.

The app will run a command every time the Discord voice settings change. In my case, it changes the color of a key on my Logitech keyboard, but you can adapt it to your own needs.

```js
const { RPClient, RPCEvent,  Presence } = require("rpcord");
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR APP CLIENT ID';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR APP CLIENT SECRET';
const DEFAULT_COLOR = '004f8b';
const DISCORD_TOKEN = 'YOUR DISCORD TOKEN';

exec(`g815-led -a ${DEFAULT_COLOR}`);

const rpc = new RPClient(CLIENT_ID, {
  secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
  scopes: ["rpc", "rpc.voice.read"],
});

function run(cmd) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) return reject(error)
      if (stderr) return reject(stderr)
      resolve(stdout)
    })
  })
}

rpc.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Connected!");
});

rpc.connect().then(() => {
  rpc.authenticate(DISCORD_TOKEN).then(() => {
    rpc.getVoiceSettings().then(voiceSettings => {
      console.log(voiceSettings);
    });

    rpc.subscribe(RPCEvent.VoiceSettingsUpdate).then((...args) => {
      console.log('subscribed !');
      rpc.on('voiceSettingsUpdate', async (voiceSettings) => {
        console.log('voice update', voiceSettings);
        if (voiceSettings.mute) {
          await run('g815-led -k g1 ff0000');
        }
        else {
          await run(`g815-led -k g1 ${DEFAULT_COLOR}`);
        }
        if (voiceSettings.deaf) {
          await run('g815-led -k g2 ff0000');
        }
        else {
          await run(`g815-led -k g2 ${DEFAULT_COLOR}`);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```